# Hashing a list and Comparing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a simple program which hashes all the values in a list of common passwords then compares the hashes to a hash value given. to then crack the password.

However it doesn't seem to work as `passwd_found` is still false and I believe its the IF statement that's not working. Any help is appreciated.

```
dic = []

passwd_hash = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93'
passwd_found = False

for k in dic:
    md5hash = hashlib.md5(k.encode('utf-8'))
    print(md5hash.hexdigest())

if passwd_hash in md5hash:
    passwd_found = True
else:
    passwd_found = False
```

Comment: Is your indenting off?

Comment: `md5hash` will equal the hash of the last string in `dic`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @ChristianDean I want to see if passwd_hash matches any of the hashed values from the list

Comment: I would check `if passwd_hash == md5hash:`, since md5 will always produce a hash of the same length (true for pretty much any hash function).

Answer (score 4):

I believe your indentation was off and you need to use `.hexdigest()` in the comparison otherwise, you get an error:

> TypeError: argument of type '_hashlib.HASH' is not iterable

```
import hashlib

dic = ['123','1234','12345','123456','1234567','12345678','password', 'qwerty','abc','abcd','abc123','111111','monkey','arsenal','letmein','trustno1','dragon','baseball','superman','iloveyou','starwars','montypython','cheese','123123','football','batman']

passwd_hash = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93'
passwd_found = False

for k in dic:
    md5hash = hashlib.md5(k.encode('utf-8'))
    t_hash = md5hash.hexdigest()
    print(t_hash)

    if passwd_hash in t_hash:
        passwd_found = True
    else:
        passwd_found = False

    if passwd_found:
        print(k) # 123123 matches
```

Comment: Also, since you're calling `hexdigest()` twice, it might be worthwhile storing both the hash and the digest to avoid duplicating finalizing the hash and then converting the digest to a hexadecimal representation.

Also, you should probably check for brute equality, or brute equality of some slice, if the hash is padded for some reason (since the hash should always produce the same number of bytes).